# Using parentheses for negative values on y-axis ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to show y-axis negative values in parentheses rather than with a negative sign. For example, rather than -2,000 I'd like to show (2,000). I'm using ggplot2 in R.

I've tried using "negative_parens = TRUE" inside of scale_y_continuous as shown below without success.

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=date, y=value, group = variable, color = variable, 
size = variable))+geom_line()+
scale_size_manual(values =c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5))+
theme_light(base_size = 16)+scale_y_continuous(labels = 
comma_format(negative_parens = TRUE), limits = c(-3500, 6000))
```

The code above does not throw an error, but still returns a y-axis labeled with negative signs rather than parentheses. Any tips on how to get negative values to appear in parentheses on the y-axis? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `scales::dollar_format` has that `negative_parens` option but the other formats like `scales::comma_format` do not. (As of current v0.4.1)

Should work with:

```
scale_y_continuous(
  labels =  scales::dollar_format(negative_parens = TRUE, prefix = ""), 
  limits = c(-3500, 6000)
)
```

For example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg - mean(mpg)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels =  scales::dollar_format(negative_parens = TRUE,
                                    prefix = "")
  )
```

[image]