# ggplot2 and scales package: the parameter negative_parens = TRUE does not work

Tags: r, plot, number-formatting

I was trying to use the scales package to produce formatting for a complex table. The following helper applies the label_percent and label_number_si functions from the scales package.

For some reason, the negative_parens = TRUE is not producing the correct output:

```
prettify_numbers_as_percent <- function(x){   
lapply(as.list(as.numeric(x)),label_percent(accuracy = 1,  suffix = "%", negative_parens = TRUE, sep = " ")) %>%

    unlist() %>%
    return() }



prettify_numbers_as_si <- function(x){
  lapply(as.list(as.numeric(x)), label_number_si(accuracy = 1,  negative_parens = TRUE, sep = " ")) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    return()
}
```

When I run

```
prettify_numbers_as_si(50000) 
prettify_numbers_as_percent(0.05)
```

I get the expected output:

> "50K"
>   "5%"

When I run

```
prettify_numbers_as_si(-50000) 
prettify_numbers_as_percent(-0.05)
```

I get the incorrect output, despite the fact that negative_parens = TRUE is set:

> "-50K"
>   "-5%"

Does anyone know why parameter setting is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that while other functions in the `scales` package have `negative_parens=` as arguments, `label_percent` and `label_number_si` do not.  Consequently, you have to write in that logic to your functions:

```
new_percent <- function(x){
  perc <- lapply(
    as.list(as.numeric(x)),
    label_percent(
      accuracy=1, suffix = '%', sep=' '
    )
  ) %>%
  unlist()

  for(i in 1:length(perc)){
    if(substring(perc[i],1,1)=='-'){
      perc[i] <- paste0('(',substring(perc[i],2),')')
    }
  }
  return(perc)
}

new_numbers <- function(x){
  nums <- lapply(
    as.list(as.numeric(x)),
    label_number_si(
      accuracy = 1,  sep = " "
    )
  ) %>%
  unlist()
  for(i in 1:length(nums)){
    if (substring(nums[i],1,1)=='-'){
      nums[i] <- paste0('(',substring(nums[i],2),')')
    }
  }
  return(nums)
}
```

Since you know each value in your return that needs to be in parentheses will start with a `"-"`, I'm using a `for` loop and `substring()` to iterate through each item and convert those that start with `"-"` to start and end with parentheses.  Works pretty well:

```
test_perc <- c(-0.5, -0.05, 1.2, .23, -0.13)
test_nums <- c(6000,-60000, 74000, -56000000)

> new_percent(test_perc)
[1] "(50%)" "(5%)"  "120%"  "23%"   "(13%)"
> new_numbers(test_nums)
[1] "6K"    "(60K)" "74K"   "(56M)"
```

Comment: I essentially landed at a similar solution. However, I am under the impression that negative_parens = TRUE used to work for label_percent and label_number_si. I'll try to investigate the change log and post an update if I find anything.

Comment: [As of 6 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699601/using-parentheses-for-negative-values-on-y-axis-ggplot2) it seems that this was a missing parameter for `label_percent`.  The fix in that example is just to use `dollar_format` and remove the `prefix=`.  You could do that here with your percent, but then you'd have to add back in `"%"` and the multiplication by 100.